# Handling Amazon SES bounce notifications to email using python imaplib

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ses, imaplib

I want to retrieve the invalid emails from mail delivery notification sent to my email endpoint from Amazon SES. I don't know how to give arguments to [imap4.search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) and [imap4.fetch()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) methods in the imaplib module.

Help please

Answer (score 0):

import imaplib
class EmailHandler:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.imap_address = 'imap.gmail.com'
    self.login_id = 'example@gmail.com'
    self.password = '******'
    self.inbox = 'desired inbox'
    self.addresses = []
    self.M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.imap_address)

def login(self):
    try:
        self.M.login(self.login_id, self.password)
        self.M.select(self.inbox)
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
        print sys.exc_info()

def extract_invalid_ids(self):
    val, data = self.M.search(None, '(OR BODY "bounce" BODY "complaint")')
    if val == 'OK':
        for num in data[0].split():
            val, data = self.M.fetch(num, '(RFC822.TEXT)')
            body = data[0][1]
            body_json_string = body.split('}}')[0] + '}}'
            body_json = json.loads(body_json_string)
            self.addresses.extend(body_json['mail']['destination'])
        print self.addresses
    else:
        print val
```

reference: http://www.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc3501.txt